# Horizontal Accordion using MooTools

Tags: javascript, mootools, horizontal-accordion

I'm trying to create a horizontal accordion menu in mootools, instead of the standard vertical one. In the manual for Fx.Accordion it says "CSS mastery is required to make width transitions work" and I guess I haven't got enough of it. Could anyone help me out on making an horizontal accordion work?

http://jsfiddle.net/Reanimation/L7Rej/2/

Comment: Try this: http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex17/haccordion.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check our kwicks from David Walsh

http://davidwalsh.name/mootools-kwicks

Hope this helps

Comment: I saw that before and thought I couldn't really use it, but now I see it again it looks pretty nice. +1 and thanks to you too! I'll try them both and see which works better.